# Pandas - Split multiple columns of numpy arrays into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I saved numpy array to pandas columns and it gets saved as a string. I parse the string and convert it to numpy array below. The issue is the code below is painfully slow. Is there a way to speed this up?

```
def f(x):
    # Remove "[" and "]" and split on space
    return np.fromstring(x[1 : -1], sep=" ")

def split_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = pd.DataFrame(np.float32(df["output"].str.replace("\n", "").apply(f).to_list()))
    other_output_df = pd.DataFrame(np.float32(df["other_output"].str.replace("\n", "").apply(f).to_list())).add_prefix("prev_")
    new_df = pd.concat((output_df, other_output_df), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    return new_df
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as text, not as a picture. Try `df.to_dict()` for your dfs. Show both input and expected output.

Comment: How did it end up a string?  Did you save a dataframe to csv file and then reload it?  That's poor practice if frame cells contain arrays (or even lists).  Array strings maybe condensed, with loss of data in the ellipses.. And as you found each string has to be converted back individually.

Comment: @hpaulj yea that's exactly what I did. Seems to work for my case but yes I agree it's bad practice. If you have another alternative feel free to suggest it.

Comment: `csv` is a 2d format, so ehen cells are lists or arrays it has to save their string equivalents (using the `str` function). For arrays that's messy.  Other SO have asked about this parsing.  `pandas` has other save methods that preserve cell contents, for example pickle.

Answer (score 0):

Without a Minimal, Reproducible Example, it is tough to diagnose possibly sub-optimal reasoning leading to a sub-optimal result; the best I can do is eliminate most redundant aspects of your code in the hopes of speeding up your implementation.

The function of `split_df(df: pd.DataFrame)` could be achieved with fewer conversions:

```
def split_df(df: pd.DataFrame):
    output_df = df["output"].str.replace("\n", "").apply(f).astype(np.float32)
    other_output_df = df["other_output"].str.replace("\n", "").apply(f).astype(np.float32).rename("prev_0")
    new_df = pd.concat((output_df, other_output_df), axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    return new_df
```